# Tomcat not shutting down within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm building a relatively simple web-app where the main servlet implements the `ServletContextListener` interface to determine whether the context has been started or stopped. I've implemented my `contextInitialized`, `contextDestroyed`, `init` and `destroy` methods (both `init` and `destroy` call `super` on the base class). I've currently implemented no real functionality other than that I've initialized log4j in the `contextInitialized` method where I load the `log4j.properties` file.

When I start and stop the Tomcat server from within Eclipse however, everything is called in the correct order (I'm using some `System.out.println`'s to test this) but after about 10 seconds of stopping the server I'm presented with an Eclipse popup stating the following:

> Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost
>   is not responding. Do you want to
>   terminate this server? Click OK to
>   terminate the server or click Cancel
>   to continue waiting.

This is what's printed in my Eclipse console when I stop the server:

> 04/01/2010 7:39:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
>   INFO: Stopping service Catalina
>   contextDestroyed 
>   04/01/2010 7:39:13 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy 
>   INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080

And after the last `INFO` message it just hangs there until the popup appears. If I choose to wait, press Cancel, Eclipse becomes unusable and I have to kill the Eclipse process from a terminal.

Any input on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The problem was caused by a non-daemon thread that I'm starting within my `init` method (forgot to mention that :). The problem was solved by explicitly stopping the thread with the `stop` method, even though that method seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Am I really the first person to use the tag 'servlet'?!?

Comment: `servlets` is the more common tag, it seems.  :)

Comment: I think this happens not only within eclipse, but in general.
As far as I recall it was a problem with log4j resources, google with that in mind.

Comment: @Luke i am facing similar problem , now i want to stop the thread but not able to understand how can i get thread reference. one option i see is i can set thread object in ServletContext attribute , but i feel its not good practice. Can you please explain how you are doing it , i mean how did u get thread reference in contextDestroyed method to stop it.

Comment: @Vipin Sorry for the delayed response. Yes, I keep references to my threads. If you don't, then like you mention, there is no way to reference them in the future.

Comment: @Luke yeah I am following same approach as explained in above comment as it is old application and people dint think about keeping reference anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg18831.html), this should be related to a cleanup issue.

> If a webapp doesn't cleanup completely, especially with respect to stopping non-daemon threads it starts, Tomcat will fail to shutdown.
>   Clicking "Stop" has the advantage of providing a timeout.
>   If Tomcat fails to stop within the timeout, a dialog will appear giving you the option to terminate the server or continue waiting.

Comment: Your answer was bang on. I've added an update to my question explaining the solution. Thanks!

Comment: well for me even when the timout happened and I got a dialog box, I clicked force Tomcat to close, even then it did not close. So I am still waiting for the Tomcat server to close. I know I can directly go and kill the deamon, but force shutdown (after the timout) should shut down the server too.

Answer (score 6):

Open Command Prompt or PowerShell in windows and type

```
netstat -nao
```

find **pid** of corresponding port from the result and type

```
taskkill /f /pid [port number]
```

Comment: how to find the pid ?

Comment: @Suresh If you are hosting on localhost:7070 for example, it will likely appear as 0.0.0.0:7070

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, open Task Manager and kill the process `javaw`.

Comment: this helped my situation.!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at your update which solved your problem also , for all others viewers of this question I want to give better approach.

Instead of using stop u should call interrupt on the thread and wrap code of run method in
 while loop which checks on !isInterrupted() , whenever interrupt is called thread will come out of loop and run method will complete its processing. Like the below example from my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492000/wait-for-recursive-thread-producer/22590964#22590964)

```
class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue;
    Consumer(BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue){
        this.blockingQueue=blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.interrupted()){
            System.out.print("Concumer Started");
            try{
                Message message  = blockingQueue.take();
                System.out.print("message Id"+message.messageId+" Consumed ");
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Concumer Done");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples:

```
taskkill /pid 1230 /pid 1241 /pid 1253 
taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /im notepad.exe 
taskkill /s srvmain /f /im notepad.exe 
taskkill /s srvmain /u maindom\hiropln /p p@ssW23 /fi "IMAGENAME eq note*" /im * 
taskkill /s srvmain /u maindom\hiropln /fi "USERNAME ne NT*" /im * 
taskkill /f /fi "PID ge 1000" /im *
```

Please use this link 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar behaviour. If closing Tomcat doesn't help try to find another active console from console view and kill it. In my case it helps.

Comment: It's not that I can't kill/stop it. I want it to shutdown properly without me shooting it though the head.

Answer (score -1):

On Mac OS X, use Activity Monitor, force quit GrailsStarter process.