# Wait for recursive Thread-Producer

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion

I have a gatherer, that searches for moves in a game. I search in a recursive search, to get every possible move from the game.

For performance cause, I use a Threadpool and every found move adds a new Thread to the pool, to maybe extend the old move.

Here is some code:

```
protected static List<Runnable> threads;
private static ExecutorService threadPool;

protected final synchronized void hookThread(Runnable thread) {
        if (threadPool == null) {
            threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
            threads = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
        }
        threadPool.execute(thread);
        threads.add(thread);
    }

protected abstract class GathererRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        onRun();
        threads.remove(this);
    }

    public abstract void onRun();

}
```

This is a snippet of the parent class. Now comes the child, that searches for the moves.

```
private void extendMove(final byte[] stones, final ByteLayMove move) {
    Runnable r = new GathererRunnable() {

        @Override
        public void onRun() {
            // fancy search stuff
            if (moveIsFound)
                extendMove(...);
        }

    };
    hookThread(r);
}
```

The problem is now, that I don't know how I should can wait for the threads to finish.

I tried to use a int, that counts up on Thread Creation and down on Thread Completion, but that also resultet in a too early search abortion.

Do you have an idea if there is a nice way to wait for these threads?
I already thought about a BlockingQueue, but I don't have any idea how to implement it properly.

Greeting Kevin

Comment: Did you use an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) or a regular `int`? The latter won't work, but the first should (using methods `incrementAndGet` and `decrementAndGet`).

Comment: Is `ArrayList` thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

Below program has implemented producer consumer scenario using BlockingQueue , you can use such approach while writing your own implementation.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class ThreadingExample {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Message>(100);
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        exec.execute(new Producer(blockingQueue));
        exec.execute(new Consumer(blockingQueue));
    }

}
class Message{
    private static int count=0;
    int messageId;
    Message(){
        this.messageId=count++;
        System.out.print("message Id"+messageId+" Created ");
    }
}
class Producer implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue;
    Producer(BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue){
        this.blockingQueue=blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.interrupted()){
            System.out.print("Producer Started");
            try {
                blockingQueue.put(new Message());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Producer Done");
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue;
    Consumer(BlockingQueue<Message> blockingQueue){
        this.blockingQueue=blockingQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.interrupted()){
            System.out.print("Concumer Started");
            try{
                Message message  = blockingQueue.take();
                System.out.print("message Id"+message.messageId+" Consumed ");
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Concumer Done");
        }
    }
}
```