# Tomcat hangs and prevents Eclipse from shutting down after running some time

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm running Eclipse 4.6.1 with in-IDE Tomcat 8.5.6 on Windows 10 Professional 64-bit Anniversary Edition.

After Tomcat is left running in Eclipse after some time, the Tomcat embedded in Eclipse can no longer be stopped. I press the red "Stop" button in the "Servers" tab, but nothing happens. Eventually Eclipse will ask me if I want to terminate Tomcat:

> Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost is not responding. Do you want to terminate this server? Click OK to terminate the server or click Cancel to continue waiting.

I click "OK to terminate the server... but Tomcat keeps running.

Unfortunately when I then try to close Eclipse, it hangs on "Saving workbench state." Finally I have to kill Eclipse, thereby losing my workbench state. Even worse, if I then start Eclipse back up and try to restart the embedded Tomcat, I get the following error:

> 'Starting Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
>
> Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

How can I surgically go in and really kill Tomcat so that it doesn't hang Eclipse and keep ports open? (Unfortunately the only thing that shows up in the task manager is Eclipse.exe. There is no Tomcat to be seen. I've tried killing the `javaw.exe` subprocess, but that doesn't help.)

(At one point I thought this was related to a VPN connection going down, but today this happened with no VPN connection at all.)

I've filed [Eclipse Bug 511342](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=511342). We'll see if anything comes of it.

Comment: Maybe you can terminate Tomcat before quitting Eclipse?

Comment: Um, that is the question. Remember that I'm running Tomcat inside Eclipse --- hence the "in-IDE" remark in the question.

Answer (score 3):

i've tried locally but i couldn't recreate the bug .

im not sure that this answers your question but it is for sure something worth trying , in any case this might show some features to other users....

in the window menu you have the `SHOW VIEW` , there you can choose other 
[image]

this open the future window with search bar and all the available views for the ide . 
[image]

in the `debug` view , you can do actions not only on applications , but on servers also . the menu here is different from the view you see in the `server`, and you can do advanced termination other things.

[image]

welp , hope that helps .

*note , you don't need the server to run in debug mode .

Answer (score 0):

Find your Tomcat installation directory, navigate to `bin` folder, open a command window there and execute an `.bat` file named `shutdown.bat`, this way you can kill tomcat directly, make sure to locate the appropiate Tomcat installation directory which Eclipse is using.

**UPDATE** - Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Interestingly when I did this the `javaw.exe` child process under `eclipse.exe` went away. However Eclipse still showed that Tomcat was "started". And when I tried to shut down Eclipse, it hung at "Saving workspace" as before.

Comment: Interesting, seems like an Eclipse installation issue to me, when you kill Tomcat from here your Tomcat instance running on Eclipse is shutted down as well (please refer to the updated answer screen shot), meaning that Eclipse should be reflecting the Server status, is your CATALINA_HOME environment variable properly set? If not, try adding it, the variable value should point at Tomcat installation root directory. Have you also tried re-installing Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it in the same way you have, but this may help.

On a command prompt (Cmd.exe) execute:

```
netstat -a -o | find "8080"
```

That will list all IP/PORT in use alongside the PID (process id) filtering by port # 8080 (change it to meet your needs or remove the find if you want to list all)
Open Task Manager, and using the PID you should be able to find the particular 
process that is using the ports you need to release. 
updated:
Once you find the port (8080) you can try using the command

```
taskkill /f /pid [port number]
```

Found a related issue with this command: [Stack overflow - Tomcat not shutting down eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998281/tomcat-not-shutting-down-within-eclipse?rq=1)

Again, I use this when I need to find a rogue thing that I need to kill, and I don't know if the embedded environment will show it separate but its worth a try.

Comment: Running this command shows `TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 mycomputer:0 LISTENING ...` and `TCP [::]:8080 mycomputer:0 LISTENING ...`. Each shows the PID of the `javaw.exe` that is the child process of `eclipse.exe`, as expected. And as I noted separately, killing this `javaw.exe` process does not solve the problem.

Comment: After killing Eclipse (which was hung trying to shut down, as explained in the description), the command you gave returns: `TCP 127.0.0.1:8080 mycomputer:54709 TIME_WAIT 0`. What does that mean? Neither the `eclipse.exe` process nor its child `javaw.exe` process exist anymore, yet something seems to be holding port 8080.

Comment: found this links to provide you with an explanation [link] (http://superuser.com/questions/67039/how-to-kill-windows-zombie-tcp-connections) <-- this will change the timeout setting for those and this other [link](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html) contains a detailed description of TIME_WAIT.  I also have another question, are there any actions you are taking when trying to close the application? or it wont ever close even with no projects loaded?

Comment: There are no other actions I'm taking. Eclipse just sits there all day, and when I come back sometimes it is in this state. I have a webapp project loaded, and Tomcat is running this webapp.

Comment: I have added an additional command as found on another similar stack overflow issue.

Answer (score -2):

In tomcat's console inside Eclipse, there's a red button that can stop it. Albert also stated that in task manager it appears as javaw.exe, however Eclipse itself also appears as javaw.exe, so be careful when killing each one. Eclipse should be the one that takes more memory.

Comment: Some task managers (on Windows) can show you the commandline so you have a better chance at identifying the right `javaw`. JConsole / VisualVM might help as well with that.

Comment: The whole point of this question is that the red button does _not_ stop Eclipse, and Eclipse says that Tomcat is not responding. And killing `javaw.exe` doesn't allow Eclipse to close --- it is still frozen at "Saving workspace."

Comment: If the problem isnt with TomCat, maybe its with the database?

Comment: What database are you talking about? And how would that relate to Tomcat?